# Horizontal swipe gesture and vertical page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I am building a mobile site and I have a slide show of images that allows sliding through images horizontally. The javascript library I'm using is bxslider. However, if one touches the slide show and wants to scroll the page up/down, the slide show blocks vertical scrolling and hence another section of the site must be touched.

Could someone please tell me how I could keep vertical scroll enabled (i.e, not allow the slideshow to block the normal scroll?)

Thanks!

Comment: Someone has already opened an [issue about this](https://github.com/wandoledzep/bxslider-4/issues/82). It might be best to just follow the progress there.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, Change the  `onTouchMove`  fn in the `bxslider` library to this

```
        var onTouchMove = function (e) {
        if (slider.settings.mode != 'fade') {
            var orig = e.originalEvent;
            var value = 0;
            // if horizontal, drag along x axis
            if (slider.settings.mode == 'horizontal')
            {   
                var hchange = orig.changedTouches[0].pageX - slider.touch.start.x;
                var vchange = orig.changedTouches[0].pageY - slider.touch.start.y;

                if(Math.abs(hchange)>20 && Math.abs(hchange)>Math.abs(vchange))
                {   
                    value = slider.touch.originalPos.left + hchange;
                    setPositionProperty(value, 'reset', 0);
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
                // if vertical, drag along y axis
            } else{
                e.preventDefault();
                var change = orig.changedTouches[0].pageY - slider.touch.start.y;
                value = slider.touch.originalPos.top + change;
                setPositionProperty(value, 'reset', 0);
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you goto the options page for the bxslider website, search for preventDefaultSwipeX, and preventDefaultSwipeY

Those are what you are looking for.